# Extracting specific data from webpage into text file

Tags: html, imacros

I have one webpage and I want to get some specific data to my text file. Is there any way to get data below? I am attaching screenshot of webpage from which I want to extract data.

```
ID No.  Name    Email   Mobile  Points  Status  Dates   Times   Point Edit  Remove
7523    punam prasad    punamprasad045@gmail.com    9300552777  1   ACTIVE  2018-02-27  11:08:11    Point Edit  Delete
```

i.e if I want to extract mobile number into text file how could i fetch data.

[image]

Comment: use data-table for exporting data as pdf,csv.. from table https://editor.datatables.net/examples/extensions/exportButtons

Comment: Is this website yours or you are trying to steal some data from another website? Do you have any code you started to work on?

Comment: I have shared admin panel detail but dont have access to cpanel